# Why can't print any statement outside the method body in class in dart

Tags: class, oop, dart, methods, printing

```
class Car {
  var name;
  var model;
  var cc;

  Car(this.name, this.model, this.cc);

  printAll() {
    print(name);
    print(model);
    print(cc);
  }

  print(name); //Showing Error
}

void main() {
  var obj = Car("Marcedes", "Class E", 5000);

  obj.printAll();
}
```

Why i can't do any kind of operation outside the method body. The code generates error in compilation which given bellow. The code write in Dartpad.
Error in Compilation. The output show

```
 Error compiling to JavaScript:
 main.dart:1:7:
 Error: The non-abstract class 'Car' is missing implementations for these members:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a method named `print` with a parameter called `name` but without a method body, i.e. an abstract method. In order to instantiate a class, Dart obviously has to know what the method body is, therefore you cannot instantiate an abstract class.

You need to do two things:

1. Because you have an abstract method, and abstract methods are only allowed in abstract classes, you need to mark `Car` as `abstract`.
2. You need to create a subclass of `Car` that overrides `print` with an implementation, and then instead instantiate *that* class.

Something like this:

```dart
abstract class Car {
    var name;
    var model;
    var cc;

    Car(this.name, this.model, this.cc);

    printAll() {
        print(name);
        print(model);
        print(cc);
    }

    print(name); // Abstract method `print` with no implementation
}

class ConcreteCar extends Car {
    ConcreteCar(name, model, cc): super(name, model, cc);

    @override
    print(name) {
        // Implementation of `print`
    }
}

void main() {
    var obj = ConcreteCar("Mercedes", "Class E", 5000);

    obj.printAll();
}
```

Note: I left the implementation of `print` empty because I didn't understand the reason for the abstract `print` method and what the goal of the design is. But it should be trivial for you to fill out the missing pieces.

Comment: Thanks.. Jörg W Mittag., I appreciate your answer.....